# Evaluating a complex integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Evaluate the integral

$$\int_{|z+1|=2} \frac{z^2}{4-z^2}dz$$

**Solution :** So $|z+1|=2$ is the circle of radius 2 centered at -1. Now inside this circle $\frac{z^2}{4-z^2}$ is analytic except for a simple pole at $z=-2$. We can write $f(z)=\frac{\phi (z)}{z+2}$ and $\phi (z)=\frac{z^2}{z-2}$. Therefore residue at -2 is -1. So the integral is $-2 \pi i$.

But the answer on the book is $2 \pi i$ is there an error in my calculation? Help please!

Answer (score 4):

seriously? :)

$$\frac{z^2}{4-z^2} = \frac{z^2}{(2-z)(2+z)} = -\frac{z^2}{(z-2)(z+2)}$$

Comment: Hi can you please put me out of my misery who is right?

Comment: Your mistake in your working occurs where you define $\phi(z)=\frac{z^2}{z-2}$, when it should be the negative of that function: $\phi(z) = \frac{z^2}{2-z}$. Both john and the answers are right. Sorry.

Comment: The book. You forgot a minus as you can see above.